# copy SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

Consider a C# application that utilizes a SQLite database. I would like an instance of my application (app #1) to be able to export its SQLite database to a file, and that file could then be imported and added to another instance of my application, app #2's SQLite database. The databases will be formatted the same way, same rows/columns, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Is there an easy way to do this? I've looked around the wrapper and the web but can't find anything of much assistance. Any help is greatly appreciated, as always.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite databases are [single files](http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html) themselves already, so if you structure your database accordingly you could get by with just copying the appropriate SQLite (.db3) file from one location to another. I think that's going to be a lot easier/simpler than any other method.